# Transform multiple columns data into one column for every groupby object

Tags: pandas, python-3.5, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df`:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1','1','2'], \
                   'diag1': ['C1.10', 'E10.40','F20.00'], \
                   'diag2': ['M30', '','O92.15'], \
                   'diag3': ['E15.34', 'H20.00','']})`

I want to create a new dataframe `df1` which should contain all the information present in `df['diag1']`, `df['diag2']` and `df['diag3']` columns based on every `ID` into one column of `df1['diag_all']`.

Should I need to use transform method in order to achieve this or is there any other function to do this?

This is what I want to achieve:

  `ID diag_all
0  1    C1.10
1  1   E10.40
2  1   F20.00
3  1      M30
4  1   O92.15
5  2   E15.34
6  2   H20.00`

Please remember that I have many other columns in the actual dataframe which I do not want to use during this transformation. So we need to specify columns in the `df` which we want to transform into `df1['diag_all']`.

Comment: do you need `df.replace('',np.nan).melt('ID').dropna()` ??

Comment: This is also great. I can then sort it out by ID and get the required results. Thanks

Comment: yes, using `sort_values()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching output `DataFrame` with some tolerance on the kind of whitespace to omit and new index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1','1','2'], \
                   'diag1': ['C1.10', 'E10.40','F20.00'], \
                   'diag2': ['M30', '','O92.15'], \
                   'diag3': ['E15.34', 'H20.00','']})

df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['diag1', 'diag2', 'diag3'], value_name='diag_all')[['ID', 'diag_all']]
df1 = df1.sort_values(['ID']).dropna().reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
print(df1)
```

```
  ID diag_all
0  1    C1.10
1  1   E10.40
2  1      M30
3  1   E15.34
4  1   H20.00
5  2   F20.00
6  2   O92.15
```